# Отображение и скрытие данных массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть набор маркеров, которые отображаются JS кодом при определенных условиях. При первом нажатии отображаются маркеры выбранного пункта, при повторном нажатии появляются снова все возможные маркеры. Но если включен 1 пункт и следовательно его маркеры, и тут ты переключаешься на другой пункт, то появляется путаница между маркерами и вместе со 2 пунктом могут показываться маркеры 1 или 3 пункта(их всего 3). А нужно чтобы при определенном включенном пункте показывались только его маркеры(даже если перешли с включенного 1 пункта, он должен отключиться). При повторном нажатии на пункт, снова все возможные.

```js
 var map = {};
 
function initialize() {
 
  var mapProp = {
    center: {
      lat: -25.363,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    zoom: 8,
    markers: []
  };
 
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
 

  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.363,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'blue',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker1);
  
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.664,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'green',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker2);
  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.365,
      lng: 131.144
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'red',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker3);
  var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.366,
      lng: 131.244
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'blue',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker4);
  var marker5 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.565,
      lng: 131.144
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'red',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker5);
  var marker6 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.666,
      lng: 131.244
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'green',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker6);
 
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.markerBtn').bind('click', function(el) {
        var catToToggle = $(this).attr('data-category'); /* категория нажатой метка */
        var catState = $(this).attr('data-state'); /* статус нажатой метки */
        if ( catState=='on') {
          $(this).attr('data-state', 'off');
        } else {
          $(this).attr('data-state', 'on');
        }
        $.each(map.markers, function() {
          if (this['category'] == catToToggle) {
            if ( catState=='on') {
              this.setVisible(true);
            } else {
              this.setVisible(true);/*отображаю эту метку в любом случае для данного пункта*/
            }
          } else {
            this.setVisible(!this.getVisible());
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>GoogleMaps</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="listGg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, #map {
            width: 800px; padding: 0; margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

.islands#redIcon {color: red;}
#name {
text-decoration: none;
}
.active>a {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px; "></div>
<div class="markerBtn" data-state="off" data-category="green">
  <a href="#" id="name" style="color: green;">1st points</a>
</div>
<div class="markerBtn" data-state="off" data-category="red">
  <a href="#" id="name" style="color: red;">2nd points</a>
</div>
<div class="markerBtn" data-state="off" data-category="blue">
  <a href="#" id="name" style="color: blue;">3rd points</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## У остальных меток надо вернуть состояние обратно

Это происходит от того, что вы не сбрасываете состояние метки с которой "ушли". Т.е. накликали метку n раз, и там остался какой-то статус, a какой - неизвестно.

Решение - сбросить статус при "уходе" с метки. Непонятно конкретно, с какой метки вы ушли, поэтому сбросим у остальных двух. Примерно так:

```
$('.markerBtn').not(this).attr('data-state', 'off');
```

если по-умолчанию они `off`

## Вы запутались в условии

Я не понял логику вашего условия, поэтому переписал

```
// если нужно показать все 
//(или off в зависимости от того что нужно первым)     
if ( catState=='on'){ 
     this.setVisible(true);//показываем независимо от цвета
}else{//если нужно показать только одного цвета
     if (this['category'] == catToToggle) {//показываем только выбранный цвет
          this.setVisible(true);
     } else {
           this.setVisible(false);
     }
}
```

## Рабочий код

```js
var map = {};

function initialize() {

  var mapProp = {
    center: {
      lat: -25.363,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    zoom: 8,
    markers: []
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);


  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.363,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'blue',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker1);

  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.664,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'green',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker2);
  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.365,
      lng: 131.144
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'red',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker3);
  var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.366,
      lng: 131.244
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'blue',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker4);
  var marker5 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.565,
      lng: 131.144
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'red',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker5);
  var marker6 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.666,
      lng: 131.244
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'green',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker6);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.markerBtn').bind('click', function(el) {
    var catToToggle = $(this).attr('data-category'); /* категория нажатой метка */
    var catState = $(this).attr('data-state'); /* статус нажатой метки */
    $('.markerBtn').not(this).attr('data-state', 'off');
    if (catState == 'on') {
      $(this).attr('data-state', 'off');
    } else {
      $(this).attr('data-state', 'on');
    }
    $.each(map.markers, function() {

      if (catState == 'on') {
        this.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        if (this['category'] == catToToggle) {
          this.setVisible(true);
        } else {
          this.setVisible(false);
        }
      }


    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>GoogleMaps</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en&callback=initMap"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="listGg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      width: 800px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    .islands#redIcon {
      color: red;
    }
    #name {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .active>a {
      font-weight: 600;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px; "></div>
  <div class="markerBtn" data-state="off" data-category="green">
    <a href="#" id="name" style="color: green;">1st points</a>
  </div>
  <div class="markerBtn" data-state="off" data-category="red">
    <a href="#" id="name" style="color: red;">2nd points</a>
  </div>
  <div class="markerBtn" data-state="off" data-category="blue">
    <a href="#" id="name" style="color: blue;">3rd points</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А в какую функция это добавлять?

Comment: @ilya1099 в вашу, на клик

Comment: он ни в какую не хочет работать. Как я его только не вставлял. Или я делаю что-то не так, или данное решение не помогает(

Comment: @ilya1099 Нужно тогда привести полный пример, вместе с html-разметкой

Comment: Исправил, добавил

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь :)